# Workstation Concurrent or Background mode (gcConcurrent) does not create a dedicated GC thread on a single-core CPU

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, clr

I have a single core server in which i am trying to enable concurrent GC in
workstation mode by changing my application config.

```
<runtime>
<gcConcurrent enabled="true"/>
```

But when I examine threads info through Windbg, I don't see any dedicated GC thread where as in multi core I can see the dedicated thread even with out enabling the concurrent mode - is the Concurrent GC supported on a single core system?

My main objective to to reduce pause time

Comment: Do you want to reduce GC pauses or increase throughput?

Comment: @usr: Yes i am trying to reduce application pause time, At present my application hangs for 3 min with 100% CPU.

Comment: @ManjunathCh and that is GC time? Does that mean your heap is 100GB in size?!

Comment: @usr: I have taken the performance dump, on analyzing the dump here is what I have  0:000> !runaway
 User Mode Time
  Thread       Time
  45:1268      0 days 0:03:24.468 . so here when I examined the call stack of that thread 45, I found out that it triggered a GC . I don't think heap size will be 100 GB.

Comment: Use PerfView to capture GC events and find out the max pause time. Don't you think that 45s GC time is unrealistically high?